# testing multiple APKs using Robotium for android testing

Tags: robotium

I want to test an application which consists of multiple APKs using a single robotium project. I am not able to do it because i am not finding a way to give more than one package name in the manifest file.
Is there any solution to this ?
Can I have a single test APK to test multiple APKs ?

Comment: Actually, it's not possible. This is limitation of android test framework.
You can take a look on: http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html
but it's supported since android 4.1

Comment: You cant test more than one apk using robotium see robotium FAQ Question..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot test an application that consist of multiple APK in a single robotium project. You can test an APK one at a time.